# on a shallow well jet pump, is it ok (on the house side) to place the service valve after a osmosis cartridge filter

Tags: plumbing

On the output side of my recently installed shallow well pump, i forgot to install the service shut off valve before running it into an osmosis type cartridge fiter. So i installed it after the filter. Before starting it up for the first time, i figured i'd get a professional opinion first.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no concern with regard to normal operation of your system. The cartridge filter should be capable of operating at the full running pressure of the water system.

The problem that could come into play is that it is normal for the service shut off valve to be used to stop any possible incoming flow of water when service or repairs need to be made to the water piping and delivery system. It would seem that your cartridge filter may fall into the category of requiring service from time to time.

In your case you may be able to work around the problem by simply cutting the power to the well pump. On the other hand if you were on a municipal or city water system this could be a bit of a problem unless you could resort to turning off the water supply at the street before the water meter.

Comment: I would think that on a jet pump, which may not be self priming, you would want the valve AHEAD of the filter so that you close off and seal the water column before you remove the filter, thus avoiding having to re-prime the pump.